# Is there a Plugin for Better Filtering the Delphi 2006 Component Palette items?

Tags: delphi, plugins, delphi-2006

I have hundreds of components in my Delphi 2006 installation, but I always have trouble finding those I haven't used before and that may be the solution for what I need at the moment. I have many undocumented packages, but by the name of the component you can have an idea of what it does.

For example:

I need a RadioButton, so I have `TRadioButton`, `TElRadioButton` or `TAdvRadioButton` to choose which one has the custom properties that I need.

But when I click the Filter Button of the Tool Palette, I have to Type from the beginning of the component name. If I could have a field editor where I could type only a part of the name and the Palette showed me the components that had that term in the middle of the name too, I would make my day!!!

**Does anyone know how in Delphi 2006?**

[image]

*I know that Delphi XE2 has this filter field.*

[image]

Comment: You don't need to filter (tested in D2007; don't have 2006 installed). Just click on the component palette where it says `Tool Palette` and type `button`, and it filters down to a list of components with `button` anywhere in the name. For instance, typing `but` shows me `TButton`, `TSpeedButton`, `TSpinButton`, `TCategoryButtons`, and `TButtonGroup` at the top (visible) part of the component palette.

Comment: @Ken, the filter behavior was changed from "starts with" to "contains" in Delphi 2007. Delphi 2005 and Delphi 2006 only ignore the leading T.

Comment: @Rob: I thought it was added with the change to the Galileo IDE; I haven't used either of them in so long I couldn't remember for sure. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: So, the answer is: move to Delphi 2007.  Delphi 2006 is buggy as heck. Get OUT of there, and get Delphi 2007. It's even (MOSTLY) binary compatible with Delphi 2006.

Comment: Will that be too much different from 2006 in code and component compatibilities? @WarrenP

Comment: Identical in every way, with fewer bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DDevExtensions IDE extension (http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/ddevextensions/) has a Component Selector that does what you need

(also using D2006, so it definitely works)